# How to teach 7 month old twins naps after lunch?

Tags: sleep, sleep-training, twins

We have twin girls, 7 month of corrected age (premies). Both get tired and cranky after lunch.

We have read that kids need regular schedules and that we should teach them to take a nap in their bed after lunch. This should be done at regular times, every day.

However we have TWO kids and they start to protest and cry as soon as we put them to bed, intensifying the problem by agitating each other. Problem is, my wife is alone during the day and so cannot calm down both kids at the same time.

Any hints on how to proceed in such a situation?

Comment: How did you handle napping/bedtime until now?

Comment: LOL, my mother used to have a chart on the refrigerator (so I am told) to list who had been fed, when we napped, etc. Nothing says both have to nap at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this seems odd, but at 7 months you just put them in a room (or separate rooms for twins) close the door and they will fall asleep eventually. If your wife is actively calming them down then they will not learn to nap, only learn how to get her attention.

This is something my wife and I read about but did not have the inner strength to do until our 3rd child and we found ourselves overwhelmed at nap AND bedtime.

My oldest is 11 now and youngest 6 and they are doing good!  (Not napping anymore, but letting them cry it out hasn't turned them into resentful children or anything like my wife and I used to think).

As a final note, my last girl did not have a favorite "blankey" like the first two did.  So, I made sure she had the same blanket all the time and eventually it helped sooth her.

At first there were days where they would be in their cribs awake for the whole time.  Sometimes crying (like an hour straight).  After a couple days they crying got much less and nap time began to be a blessing for all of us.

While I was very apprehensive about 'abandoning them' the professionals were right about them surviving and growing to adapt to this new routine.  They also learned to be alone and that Mom and Dad would always be back for them.

Comment: While it may be useful to know someone's else experiences (so thank you for your answer :) ), please note that the fact that *your* children are "doing good" is irrelevant in the general context. I wouldn't ever recommend anything based only on an anecdotal evidence.